# SQL syntax error with substring and charindex

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, charindex

I have this script:

```
update edi_file_steps
  set
    user_id= table_B.id,
    message= SUBSTRING( message, 1, CHARINDEX('[',message)-1)
from edi_file_steps table_A INNER JOIN GU_User table_B
where message LIKE '%Downloaded%' 
  AND table_B.login = SUBSTRING( 
    message, 
    CHARINDEX('[', message) + 1, 
    len(message) - CHARINDEX('[',message)-1
  );
```

I am getting sql syntax error at line 4: unexpected token , 
Is there any thing wrong with my script ?sql

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am doing this script with java api named liquibase, in should be a pure sql syntax in order to work with databases like mysql or hsqldb ...

Comment: Even when I tried with mysql database, I am getting syntax error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you have a malformed `JOIN`.  And very poor table aliases.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
update fs
    set user_id = u.id,
        message = SUBSTRING(fs.message, 1, CHARINDEX('[', fs.message)-1)
    from edi_file_steps fs INNER JOIN
         GU_User u
         on u.login = SUBSTRING(fs.message, CHARINDEX('[', fs.message)+1, len(fs.message)- CHARINDEX('[',fs.message)-1 )
    where message LIKE '%Downloaded%' ;
```

EDIT:

In MySQL, this would be:

```
update edi_file_steps fs INNER JOIN
       GU_User u
       on fs.message like concat('%[', u.login, ']%')
    set user_id = table_B.id,
        message = substring_index(fs.message, '[', 1)
    where message LIKE '%Downloaded%' ;
```

Comment: doesn't work, this doesn't work with liquibase java, also I tried with mysql database without using any api, I am getting this:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from edi_file_steps fs INNER JOIN GU_User u
            on u.login = SUBSTRING( ' at line 4

Comment: In all cases I am getting sql syntax error line 4 near on u.login = SUBSTRING ...

Comment: @AymenRagoubi . . . Why are you using SQL Server syntax if your underlying database is MySQL?  I adjusted the answer.

Comment: because I am using a java api LIQUIBASE that does like a version control of my database, so It should be a pure sql so that when we change our database we don't have to touch code.

Comment: I know, but I want a pure sql syntax, your first answer should work on mysql, why I am getting syntax error near u.login=substring...

Comment: I want the script to work on mysql database and alse on hsqldb, my script should be pure sql so that it works on mysql and hsqldb and other relational databases

Comment: @AymenRagoubi . . . This answers the question that you have asked here, which is about a syntax error in a particular SQL statement.

Comment: Yes but It doesn't work, do you have an idea why I am still getting syntax error, I tried with mysql 5.7

Comment: why you closed the new question that I posted so

Comment: @AymenRagoubi . . . It looked like a duplicate of this question.